# Why animation does not stop after loop meets condition

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, while-loop

The characters move from one side of he screen to the other. The movement finishes when the while loops is done executing but the "Run" animation keeps going.

```
void Update()
{ 

if(selected == true)
Move()

}

void Move() 
{

pos = left.transform.position;

StartCoroutine(MoveOverTime());

IEnumerator MoveOverTime()
        {
            while (transform.position != pos)
            
            {
               
                transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, pos, 0.04f * Time.deltaTime);
                animator.Play("Run");
                yield return null;
            }
       selected = false;
     yield return null;

      }
}
```

Comment: Well given pos is made of floats. Highly likely the 2 values are never exactly equal

Answer (score 0):

You should use a proper float comparison to prevent the expected almost-never-exactly-same-value condition.

Try to use `(transform.position - pos).magnitude > 0.1f` instead. You can tweak the precision as you wish.

Comment: sorry but while ((transform.position - pos).magnitude < 0.1f) does not execute at all

Comment: @cfdoh sorry. It was supposed to be > instead. I hope you already figured that out.